# integrate chrome tab bar with ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

I need your help with a customization issue please.
I'm a sucker for small details and my OCD starts acting up if things aren't my way.
so, I've installed the latest google chrome on ubuntu, now how do I go about getting the green (+) sign on the tab bar (the one you hit to open a new tab) and how to get the (x) sign (the one you hit to close the tab) to look like the one from the native firefox that comes with ubuntu.
Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You can have the + for a new tab added: [Chrome Theme 1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firefox-1366x768/cjpflleobanlnllpgeddgckjhjchagmj?hl=en-GB)

You could also edit Google Chrome's icons, saved in `/usr/share/icons/`.